# Как реализовать отправку и получение сообщений в чате?

Tags: android, чат, отправка

Разбираюсь с логикой отправки и приема сообщений, чтобы получать и отправлять сообщения в чат. Только не могу понять почему те сообщения которые я получаю прилетают справа ( с той же стороны, что и отправляю). Кто подскажет, как прописать чтоб распознавать полученные сообщения и помещать их слева? Привожу свой код ниже.

```
    public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ChatViewHolder> {

public static final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 1;
public static final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 0;
ArrayList<String> messages;
LayoutInflater inflater;
DataChat dataChat;

public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ChatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case MSG_TYPE_RIGHT:
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_chat, parent, false);
            return new ChatViewHolder(view);
        case MSG_TYPE_LEFT:
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_chat_left, parent, false);
            return new ChatViewHolder(v);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String msg = messages.get(position);
    holder.tvMessage.setText(msg);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messages.size();

}
@Override
public final int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (dataChat.isMine()) return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
    else return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
}

class ChatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvMessage;
    ChatViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
    }
}

static class DataChat {

    private boolean isMine;
    private String content;

    DataChat(String message, boolean mine) {
        content = message;
        isMine = mine;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public boolean isMine() {
        return isMine;
    }

    public void setIsMine(boolean isMine) {
        this.isMine = isMine;
    }
}
```

}

```
    public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

RelativeLayout relative_layout;
Button btn_message_chat;
EditText et_message, edId;
ImageView iv_smile_chat, iv_camera_chat, iv_gallery_chat, iv_gif_chat, iv_highsignal_chat;
ListView listView;
TextView tvMessage;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
WebSocket ws;
private static final String TAG = "My Log Test";
private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private DataAdapter dataAdapter;
private MessageActivityViewModel messageActivityViewModel;
public SocketManger sm;
private static Handler h;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat_send);

    messageActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MessageActivityViewModel.class);

    // Передача данных в LiveData
    MutableLiveData<List<Message>> liveDataLoadHistory = messageActivityViewModel.getLiveDataLoadHistory();
    liveDataLoadHistory.observe(this, new Observer<List<Message>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Message> messages) {
            for (Message msg: messages) {
                arrayList.add(msg.getText());
            }

            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    messageActivityViewModel.getLiveDataSendMsg().observe(this, new Observer<String>(){

        @Override
        public void onChanged(String s) {
            if(s.equals(ENTER_EMPTY_MSG)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Вы ввели пустое сообщение", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                return;
            }

            if(s.equals(VERY_LONG_MSG)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Вы ввели очень длинное", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                return;

            }

            arrayList.add(s);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            int newMsgPosition = arrayList.size() - 1;
            dataAdapter.notifyItemInserted(newMsgPosition);
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(newMsgPosition);
            et_message.setText("");
        }
    });

    App myApp = (App) getApplication();
    sm = myApp.getSocketManger();
    sm.setHandler(h);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.message_recycler);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplication());
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList );
    recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    et_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
    relative_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
    tvMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
    iv_smile_chat = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_smile_chat);
    iv_camera_chat = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_camera_chat);
    iv_gallery_chat = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_gallery_chat);
    iv_gif_chat = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_gif_chat);
    iv_highsignal_chat = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_highsignal_chat);
    btn_message_chat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_message_chat);
    edId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edId);
    iv_smile_chat.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_message_chat.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String method = "message/send";

    String to = edId.getText().toString();
    String text = et_message.getText().toString();
    String attachments = "";
    String type = "";
    String file_id = "";
    String message_id = "";
    String url = "";
    String vote_id = "";
    String product_id = "";
    String user_id = "";
    String group_id = "";

    messageActivityViewModel.sendMessageToServer(method, to, text, attachments, type, file_id, message_id, url,
            vote_id, product_id, user_id, group_id);
}
```

}

item_chat

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingVertical="10dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:paddingLeft="60dp"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:id="@+id/rl_right"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_right"
        android:text="Placeholder message"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

item_chat_left

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingVertical="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="60dp"
android:id="@+id/rl_left"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingVertical="12dp"
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_left"
    android:text="Hello////// How are you?" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Массив объектов класса для отправки сообщений у меня такой

```
public class MessageDTO {

private String method;
private String to;
private String text;
private String attachments;
private String type;
private String file_id;
private String message_id;
private String url;
private String vote_id;
private String product_id;
private String user_id;
private String group_id;


public MessageDTO(String method, String to, String text, String attachments, String type, String file_id, String message_id, String url,
                  String vote_id, String product_id, String user_id, String group_id) {
    this.method = method;
    this.to = to;
    this.text = text;

    this.attachments = attachments;
    this.type = type;
    this.file_id = file_id;
    this.message_id = message_id;
    this.url = url;
    this.vote_id = vote_id;
    this.product_id = product_id;
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.group_id = group_id;

}
```

}

Сериализация веденного сообщения и отправка на сервер  (SocketManager)

```
public void messageText(String method, String to, String text, String attachments, String type, String file_id, String message_id, String url, String vote_id, String product_id, String user_id, String group_id, boolean isMine, Response1 response) {

    MessageDTO messageDTO = new MessageDTO(method, to, text, attachments, type, file_id, message_id, url,
            vote_id, product_id, user_id, group_id, isMine);

    System.out.println(isMine);


    try {

        if (text.equals("")) {

            response.responseErrorCallback1(ENTER_EMPTY_MSG);

        } else if (text.length() == MAX_MESSAGE_LENGHT) {
            response.responseErrorCallback1(VERY_LONG_MSG);


        } else {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json1 = gson.toJson(messageDTO);
            System.out.println(json1);
            Log.v(TAG, "Сообщение отправлено!" + text.toString());
            ws.sendText(String.valueOf(json1));
            response.responseCallback1(messageDTO);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Потом колбэком возвращается класс объектов и помещается в liveData

```
@Override
                public void responseCallback1(MessageDTO result) {
                    liveDataSendMsg.postValue(result);
                }

                @Override
                public void responseErrorCallback1(String result) {
                    liveDataSendMsg.postValue(result);
                }
            });
}
```

Теперь здесь я вытаскиваю из liveData этот  класс объектов. И добавляю его в ArrayList   методом  arrayList.add(s);

```
messageActivityViewModel.getLiveDataSendMsg().observe(this, new Observer<Object>(){


        @Override
        public void onChanged(Object s) {


            if(s.equals(ENTER_EMPTY_MSG)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Вы ввели пустое сообщение", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                return;
            }

            if(s.equals(VERY_LONG_MSG)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Вы ввели очень длинное", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                return;

            }
            arrayList.add(s);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });
```

И в dataAdapter пытаюсь вытащить с ArrayList нужные объекты, но в методе public int getItemCount() { return messages.size(); } приходит 0.

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public static final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 1;
public static final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 0;

ArrayList<MessageDTO> messages;
LayoutInflater inflater;


public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MessageDTO> messages) {

    this.messages = messages;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case MSG_TYPE_RIGHT:
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_chat, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        case MSG_TYPE_LEFT:
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_chat_left, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        default:
            return null;
    }


}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        MessageDTO msg = messages.get(position);
        holder.tvMessage.setText(msg.getText());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messages.size();
}
@Override
public final int getItemViewType(int position) {
    MessageDTO msg = messages.get(position);

    if (msg.isMine()) return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
    else return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
}



static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvMessage;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.tvMessage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: покажите разметку элементов списка

Comment: Добавила разметку выше.

Comment: у вас разметка для правой стороны имеет два тега которые переносят view к правому краю экрана, уберите одby из них, например этот - `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`  и этот тег  в textview - `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` я думаю нужно убрать

Comment: Я убрала, но только мою проблему это не решило. Мне нужно знать как распознавать сообщения которые приходят и которые я отправляю.

Comment: вы в адаптер передаете строку, а по строке вы никак не определите кому принадлежит письмо: вам или отправителю. Лучше передавать массив объектов класса, но я не увидел у вас в коде как вы получаете данные с сервера. приложите данный код или укажите где именно происходит получение данных с сервера

Comment: Я добавила массив объектов выше.

Comment: добавление в адаптер - `arrayList.add(msg.getText());` вы передаете текст и в конструкторе тоже - `ArrayList<String> messages` а вам нужно передавать что-то типа `ArrayList<MessageDTO>()` и в нем будут объекты класса сообщений, и тогда вы сможете отслеживать от какого типа приходит письмо

Comment: @ Andrew, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно создать свой кастомный ArrayList, наподобе.

```
public class Message {
public String mess;
public Boolean get;



public void setID(String mess Boolean get) {
    this.mess= mess;
    this.get= get;
}
```

После стоит его заполнить данными.

```
                    List<Message > mess= new ArrayList<>();
                    mess.add(new Message ("Сообщение", 1));
```

mess- сообщение
get-переменная, служащая для проверки получил или отправил сообщение

и использовать в адаптере

```
 MessagesAdapter msgs = new Messages(mess);
```

public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    // final ImageView avatar;
    final TextView txtMSG;


    PersonViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        //     avatar = view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        txtMSG = view.findViewById(R.id.txtMes);


    }
}

public ArrayList<Message> mess;


public Messages(List<Message> mess) {
    this.mess= mess;

}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}


@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {


    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_left, viewGroup, false);
    return new PersonViewHolder(v);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.txtMSG.setText(mess.get(position).getString("msg"));

    if (mess.get(position).get) {


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.weight = 1.0f;
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;


        viewHolder.txtMSG.setLayoutParams(params);


    } else {


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.weight = 1.0f;
        params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;


        viewHolder.txtMSG.setLayoutParams(params);


    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mess.size();
}
```

}

Comment: спасибо большое.